# How to convert an address from firebase into latitude and longtiude

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

Suppose you retrieve an user address from firebase console and want the address convert into lat and long. How do i go doing about it?

I have tried the following way.

```
ref.once('value', (request) => {
       var currentUserAddress = request.val().regdetails.address;
        var latlng = new LatLng(40.7128, -74.0059);
         var userAddress = new LatLng(currentUserAddress)
        console.log(userAddress);
    });
```

I have tried to get the declare a new variable userAddress with a new LatLng(currentUserAddress) but it doesn't allow me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with following code

**1. Add following script into index.html file**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

**2. Edit your exiting code**

```
ref.once('value', (request) => {
  var currentUserAddress = request.val().regdetails.address;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': currentUserAddress}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.latitude;
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.longitude;
      var latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      var userAddress = new LatLng(currentUserAddress)
      console.log(userAddress);
    } 
  }); 

});
```

I hope its work for you.